# How to add supporting file in jar using gradle script

Tags: java, jar, build.gradle

I have created a jar file using gradle.
How to add supporting file to this jar file

My file structure is

```
       common\src\com\sp\

            in this I have a java file

       common\src\bundle

            in this I have a property file
```

my build.gradle is in common package

I have  run my  gradle I got jar file

I have extract a jar file I have  class file only I didn't get a property file how to get property files in my gradle

my buld.gradle is given bellow

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'

    dependencies {

        compile files ('lib/commons-codec-1.8.jar')
        compile files ('lib/trinidad-api.jar')
        compile files ('lib/javax.ejb_3.0.1.jar')
        compile files ('lib/toplink-grid.jar')
        compile files ('lib/trinidad-impl.jar')
        compile files ('lib/javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar')
        compile files ('lib/javax.jsp_1.2.0.0_2-1.jar')
        compile files ('lib/adfm.jar')
             compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    }   
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure is not following any conventions. The resource directory should not be under the src.  It could be a sibling of src. Please see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html for some ideas.

If you want to make it work: The java plugin has many properties, one of them is for resources- **resources**

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir = 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/bundle'
        }
    }

}
```